# Missing function names in Lua stack traceback

Tags: debugging, lua, traceback

I'm trying to improve error handling in my program that runs a Lua script.
Simplified version:

```
function _errH(msg)

    print(msg .. "\n" .. debug.traceback(nil, 1))

end

function _main()

  -- cause some random error
  print(a-2)

end

function main()

    xpcall(_main, errH)
end

main()
```

Gives me the following call stack (please ignore the wrong line numbers):

```
stack traceback:
    [string ""]:7428: in function '__sub'
    [string ""]:7651: in function <[string ""]:7432>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    [string ""]:7658: in function 'main'
    [string ""]:7928: in main chunk
```

Now I'm  wondering why there is `[string ""]` everywhere.

Is there any way to influence these missing texts? Do I have to name the functions in addition to defining them?
Why do I see `in function '__sub'` but not `in function '_main'` for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can assign the chunk name when [loading](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_load). The auxiliary function use `lua_load` and most will set the chunk name based on the type of content being loaded:

- `lua_load` accepts a chunk name
- `luaL_loadfile` will use the filename
- `luaL_dofile` uses `luaL_loadfile`
- `luaL_loadstring` will use the string contents
- `luaL_dostring` uses `luaL_loadstring`
- `luaL_loadbuffer` accepts a chunk name

If you look at the source code for [luaL_loadstring](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_loadstring):

```
LUALIB_API int luaL_loadstring (lua_State *L, const char *s) {
  return luaL_loadbuffer(L, s, strlen(s), s);
}
```

Notice that its really just a convenience function that calls `luaL_loadbuffer` with the string as the chunk name. So, what is needed is to load your code from strings like:

```
luaL_loadbuffer(L, s, strlen(s), "=my_chunk");
```

Where `"=my_chunk"` is the name of the chunk that will appear in the [debug information](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.9).

The equal sign before the name changes the trace back:

```
my_chunk:1: in main chunk
```

Where omitting the equal sign will show:

```
[string "my_chunk"]:1: in main chunk
```

Answer (score 3):

That `[string ""]` comes from the way you're loading chunks into vm. You didn't supply filename as argument to lua_dofile/lua_loadfile/lua_dostring/lua_loadstring, or just gave empty string there. 
And note that string is the name of lua file (lua chunk), and not the name of function.